# using Retrofit2/okhttp3 upload file,the upload action always performs twice,one fast ,and other slow

Tags: java, okhttp, retrofit2

I use a ProgressRequestBody to show a progress for the upload action.

```
@Override
public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
    // see https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1587
    // JakeWharton commented on 28 Apr 2015  's answer
    final BufferedSink progressSink = Okio.buffer(new ForwardingSink(sink) {
        long bytesWritten = 0L;
        long contentLength = 0L;

        @Override
        public void write(Buffer source, long byteCount) throws IOException {
            if (contentLength == 0) {
                contentLength = contentLength();
            }
            bytesWritten += byteCount;
            mListener.onProgressUpdate(bytesWritten,contentLength,bytesWritten == contentLength);
            System.out.println("--byte--"+bytesWritten);
            super.write(source, byteCount);
        }
    });
    requestBody.writeTo(progressSink);
    System.out.println("--byte-- start---");
    progressSink.flush();
    System.out.println("--byte-- end---");
}
```

this method was called twice every time I performed the action of upload.
at first, I considered the problem may be the Interceptor which was added into okhttpclient for log,but it was not. who could help me? thanks

more code :

```
public interface UploadInterface {

@Multipart
@POST("path")
Call<JsonBase<Result>> uploadFile(
        @Query("_appTicket") String cookie, 
        @Query("Id") String id, 
        @Part MultipartBody.Part requestBody
);
}
```

upload action:

```
final ProgressRequestBody progressRequestBody
                            = new ProgressRequestBody(
                            RequestBody.create(
                                    MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),
                                    tempZip
                            )
                    );
MultipartBody.Part part = MultipartBody.Part
                            .createFormData("file","upload",progressRequestBody);
                    final Call<JsonBase<JsonUploadResult>> call 
                            = uplocaInterface.uploadFile(cookie,s,part);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems you are using HttpLoggingInterceptor which called writeTo for the Request body. You could ignore the issue as HttpLoggingInterceptor should be disabled for release builds or overwrite intercept method of HttpLoggingInterceptor and disable it for this particular upload request.

Answer (score 2):

I used this code to tracking http request progress.

```
    @Override
    public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
        Source source = null;
        try {
            source = Okio.source(file);
            long total = 0;
            long read;
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

            while ((read = source.read(sink.buffer(), SEGMENT_SIZE)) != -1) {
                total += read;
                sink.flush();

                final int percent = (int) (total / (float)file.length() * 100);

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        listener.transferred(percent);
                    }
                });
            }
        } finally {
            Util.closeQuietly(source);
        }
    }
```

Remove all http client interceptors to avoid method called twice.

Comment: Thanks @Hendi remove http inteceptors and it worked perfect for me. saved my day.

Answer (score -1):

Hi check the below blog article

https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server

It has good explanation with example for your problem.